# Pyspark : Need to join multple dataframes i.e output of 1st statement should then be joined with the 3rd dataframse and so on

Tags: python, pyspark

```
    if i >= length and i > 2:
            j=j+1
            print i
            print j
        #line.show()
            second="newdf{}" .format(j +1)
            first="newdf{}" .format(j)
            third="newdf{}" .format(j +2)
            print first
            print second
            print third
           # newdf1.show()
            print "one"
        #if (line == "/MTDSumOfCustomerInitiatedTrxn"):
            #first="enhanced_df{}" .format(i -1)
            #print first

            #first.show()
            #final=enhanced_df{}.join(enhanced_df{},'ENT_CUST_ID','outer') .format(i,i -1)


            #stat="{},{}" .format(first,second)
            #print stat
            b="prevDf=GenericFunctions.enhanced_customer({},{},'ENT_CUST_ID')" .format(second,first)
            print b
            exec(b)
            prevDf.show(i)

            c= "Finaldf=GenericFunctions.enhanced_customer(prevDf,{},'ENT_CUST_ID')" .format(third)
```

For eg: I have 5 df (df1,df2,df3,df4,df5). I should be able to join the df1 with df2 and store in prevdf, then I should be able to join prevdf with df3, and the result of this join with df4 and so on, I am able to join if I have 3 dataframe, but not able to join with df4.

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does your code has that much blank lines?

Comment: Nope , it was commented portion which i removed before putting it , my bad i should have formatted it more appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I tried my way, using udf. Just take care of column names properly.

```
>>> l = [(1,2,3,4),(3,4,5,6)]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(l,['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
>>> df.show()
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|   4|
|   3|   4|   5|   6|
+----+----+----+----+

>>> l = [(1,7,8,9),(3,9,5,7)]
>>> df1 = spark.createDataFrame(l,['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
>>> df1.show()
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   7|   8|   9|
|   3|   9|   5|   7|
+----+----+----+----+

>>> l = [(1,89,45,67),(3,23,34,56)]
>>> df2 = spark.createDataFrame(l,['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
>>> df2.show()
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|  89|  45|  67|
|   3|  23|  34|  56|
+----+----+----+----+

>>> l = [(3,65,21,32),(1,87,64,35)]
>>> df3 = spark.createDataFrame(l,['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
>>> df3.show()
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   3|  65|  21|  32|
|   1|  87|  64|  35|
+----+----+----+----+

>>> l = [(1,99,101,345),(3,67,53,21)]
>>> df4 = spark.createDataFrame(l,['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
>>> df4.show()
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|  99| 101| 345|
|   3|  67|  53|  21|
+----+----+----+----+

>>> def join_udf(df0,*df):
...    for id,d in enumerate(df):
...        if id == 0:
...           prevdf = df0.join(d,'col1')
...        else:
...           prevdf = prevdf.join(d,'col1')
...    return prevdf
...
>>> jdf = join_udf(df,df1,df2,df3,df4)
>>> jdf.show()
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col2|col3|col4|col2|col3|col4|col2|col3|col4|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|   4|   7|   8|   9|  89|  45|  67|  87|  64|  35|  99| 101| 345|
|   3|   4|   5|   6|   9|   5|   7|  23|  34|  56|  65|  21|  32|  67|  53|  21|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh , Can you suggest a way on how to get rid duplicate columns when joining.

Comment: You got to just select from prevdf which all columns you need.